# Why when I'm slicing this array in a nested for loop is it going on an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, slice

newbie JavaScript question.

This function is supposed to make a route cipher out of a given string.

Why is this resulting in an infinite loop?

```
function routecipher(string, rows, columns){
  var mArray = string.split('')
  var newArray = []
  for (i = columns; i < mArray.length; i+=columns) {
    for (j = 0; j < mArray.length - columns; j+columns){
    newArray.push(mArray.slice(j, i))
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: There were several blunders. What was causing the infinite loop was j+columns instead of j+=columns. This is the new **working** code.

```
function encryption(string, r, c){
  
  var mArray = string.split('')
  var newArray = []
  for (i = c; i <= mArray.length; i+=c) {
    for (j = i - c; j < i; j+=c){
    newArray.push(mArray.slice(j, i))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because in the second loop there is no assignment on the 3rd parameter of the loop. Maybe you meant “j += columns” instead of just “j+columns”.

Answer (score 1):

I think you really want to do like:

```js
function routecipher(string, columns, rows = Infinity){
  let s = string.split(''), a = [], r = 0;
  while(s.length && r < rows){
    a.push(s.splice(0, columns)); r++;
  }
  return a;
}
console.log(routecipher('I have no idea what this string is supposed to contain', 3));
console.log(routecipher('I have no idea what this string is supposed to contain', 4, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `j+columns` should be `j+=columns`. The equal sign is missing.